# Alias Record not working in Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Been through a couple of tutorials, AWS official docs and SO questions, and still can't get my Route53 Alias to work.

I've done this in the past, but for some reason on this particular domain – `www.tallyhaus.com`, the same steps I've taken before just don't seem to work.

I'm 100% sure of the following:

- bucket name matches the alias record name
- my bucket is reachable: the s3 endpoint offered by the bucket works, and is hittable
- the NS entries are the same on my registered domain, as in my NS record on my hosted zone

The domain in question is `www.tally.haus`.

The only different thing I can think of is that I have a subdomain for my API, which lives under `api.tally.haus`, and that NS record points to the NSs on my Lightsail instance – but I created a separate hosted zone for that subdomain.

I even tried creating a CloudFront distribution to see if that works, and still nothing.

Ideas?

Thanks

**NOTE**: Endpoint that I'm talking about, the one that isn't resolving, is `www.tally.haus`.

Comment: `www.tally.haus` seems to be working fine, through CloudFront.  There don't seem to be any records in you main hosted zone for `api.tally.haus` and there is no reason why you needed to create a separate hosted zone for a subdomain -- I suspect you have misinterpreted the documentation.  It's not clear if "api" is what you are talking about not working, or another subdomain.

Comment: Talking about the main domain, `www.tally.haus`.

Yep! I can see that I didn't notice that [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html) refers to subdomains when you **don't want to move the parent domain to Route53**.
    
Still, `www.tally.haus` doesn't resolve for me.
 
Even `host -a www.tally.haus` just says `Host www.tally.haus not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`.

Comment: That's strange... from where I am (in Kentucky), the www address is resolving fine, sending me to a CloudFront edge in Atlanta.

Comment: What are you using to see that? I'm straight up trying to hit it in Chrome, and not seeing anything...

Comment: Can I have a separate NS record for a subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

*Step-by-step example*

1. Create a bucket with the name `mysite.tally.haus`
2. Activate static website hosting on the bucket. Website endpoint will be
   similar to this: http://mysite.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
3. Add index.html to the bucket
4. Make the index.html public
5. In Route53 add an A-Record, click on Alias and type in appropriate S3 Website endpoint depending on your S3 bucket location.
   For this use case, it is : `s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.`

*Record set will look like this:*

```
mysite.tally.haus.  A ALIAS s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.
```

Amazon Simple Storage Service Website Endpoints:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: Literally **exactly** what I did – and have always done.

I'll note that the region does change, but I do believe I have the appropriate region (Route53 doesn't let you proceed anyway, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Again, most of those points I stated in the original question. And even using Cloudfront, doesn't seem to resolve.

Comment: And the domain I'm referring to is `www.tally.haus`, as stated in the question.

Comment: I guess the nameserver you are connected to is not updated yet, or you have wrong record information in the DNS cache. The site www.tally.haus is working for me.

Comment: If you are using Windows you can do: ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: On a Mac. Found a way to do it. Do you actually see a page?

I believe the nameservers are updated, and they both show the same values – both for the hosted zone and the registered domain.

I already flushed, and still can't see anything. Had some other people check too, and they can't pull anything up. Could it be region based?

Comment: Yes. www.tally.haus/board is visible (http, not https).